# How to obtain all classical simple Lie superalgebras of rank 2?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-superalgebras

I'm reading Musson's book on "Lie superalgebras and Enveloping Algebras" as well Kac' Advances paper on this subject. In both references the rank 2 classical simple Lie superalgebras just appear at some point. There is no word about **how** to obtain this **complete** list.
My questions: Do you know a reference? Or do you have a hint how to obtain this list by myself?